# Find all triples $(a,b,c)$ giving $3$ powers of $3$ simultaneously

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

> For which triples $(a,b,c)$ of positive integers are $2a+b,2b+c,2c+a$ all powers of $3$ ?

I found out that $a, b, c$ have the same remainder after division by $3$.

Comment: Hi @Heipl, please attach your attempt so that we can help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: A trivial set of solutions can be found when $a=b=c=3^n$, where $n$ is any nonnegative integer. I'm curious to see any nontrivial solutions, should they exist.

Comment: The only "non-trivial" solution I found so far is $(1,7,13)$ which can be multiplied with any power of $3$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no solutions except those already mentioned by **Prometheus** ($a=b=c=3^n$) and **Peter** ($1,7,13$ times a power of 3).

1. Suppose there is a solution where not all three numbers are equal; say, $c$ is the (non-strictly) biggest of them. Now, since $2c+a=3^n$, it follows that $3^{n-1}\leqslant c < 3^n/2$.
2. Then $2b+c$, which also has to be a power of $3$, is too big for $3^{n-1}$ and too small for $3^{n+1}$, so it has no other choice except to be $3^n$ too. So $2c+a=2b+c$, or $c+a=2b$, hence $b={a+c\over2}>c/2\geqslant3^{n-1}/2$.
3. Now $2a+b$ is too big for $3^{n-2}$ and too small for $3^n$, hence $2a+b=3^{n-1}$, or $\frac52a+\frac12c=3^{n-1}$. Also, $2c+a=3^n$. This solves to yield $(a,b,c)=3^{n-3}\cdot(1,7,13)$.

So it goes.

Comment: My understanding is that since the triples are ordered in the final rendering they should be enclosed by parentheses not braces (the latter used for unordered sets). Feel free to roll back if inappropriate.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is better this way.